# Using the subprocess library: error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, subprocess, argparse

So essentially I have 15 or so scripts that can connect to various networking devices using an SSH library. I want to create one top-level python file that can run other python scripts so the user can decide which scripts they want to run. I have been advised to use the subprocess library and this seems to make the most sense for what I want to do. It is important to note that my python scripts contain command-line argparse arguments for it to run, for example:

```
python San_cable_test.py -deviceIP 172.1.1.1 -deviceUsername myUsername -devicePassword myPassword
```

So far I have created a top-level python file that is set up to call two python scripts to start with that the user can enter. However, when I run the program and select one of the options and get the user arguments, I get a

```
error: unrecognized arguments:
```

I tried it two different ways and I'll show the tracebacks:

```
usage: San_cable_test.py [-h] [-deviceIP DEVICEIP]
The name of this script is: San_cable_test.py
                         [-deviceUsername DEVICEUSERNAME]
                         [-devicePassword DEVICEPASSWORD]
San_cable_test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 172.1.1.1 myUsername myPassword
```

and

```
usage: San_cable_test.py [-h] [-deviceIP DEVICEIP]
                         [-deviceUsername DEVICEUSERNAME]
The name of this script is: San_cable_test.py
                         [-devicePassword DEVICEPASSWORD]
San_cable_test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -deviceIP 172.1.1.1 -deviceUsername myUsername -devicePassword myPassword
```

This is my first time using the subprocces library and I don't know if I'm calling these scripts right. The problem is that these scripts are run in the command line using argparse, so that's the issue. Unfortunately I am using 2.7.16 because of this weird company thing and I've been trying to get my managers to know that 2.7 is going to be unsupported soon but that's not relevant as of now. Here is the important part of my code. I really appreciate the help!

```
def runMain():

    scriptName = os.path.basename(__file__)

    print("The name of this script: " + scriptName + "\n")

    scriptPurpose = 'This script is the top-level module that can invoke any script the user desires !\n'

    while True:
        optionPrinter()

        user_input = input("Please select an option for which your heart desires...\n")

        switch_result = mySwitch(user_input)

        if switch_result == "our_Switch":
            deviceIP = raw_input("Enter the IP address for the device")
            deviceUsername = raw_input("Enter the username for the device")
            devicePassword = raw_input("Enter the password for the device")

            subprocess.call(['python', 'our_Switch.py', deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword])

        elif switch_result == "San_cable_test":
            deviceIP = raw_input("Enter the IP address for the device")
            deviceUsername = raw_input("Enter the username for the device")
            devicePassword = raw_input("Enter the password for the device")
            subprocess.call(['python', 'San_cable_test.py', deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword])

        else:
            print("Exiting the program now, have a great day !\n")
            sys.exit(-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Here is the an example of argparse being used in one of the scripts

```
def runMain():

    scriptName = os.path.basename(__file__)

    print("The name of this script is: " + scriptName)

    scriptPurpose = 'This script enables and disables the SAN switches'

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=scriptPurpose, formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-deviceIP", help="Target device IP address", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-deviceUsername", help="Target device username", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-devicePassword", help="Target device password", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.deviceIP is None:
        print("The device IP parameter is blank\n")
    else:
        deviceIP = args.deviceIP

    if args.deviceUsername is None:
        print("The device userName parameter is blank\n")
    else:
        deviceUsername = args.deviceUsername

    if args.devicePassword is None:
        print("The device password parameter is blank\n")
    else:
        devicePassword = args.devicePassword

    print("**********************\n")
    print (deviceIP + " " + deviceUsername + " " + devicePassword)
    print("**********************\n")

    print("This script allows the user to enable and disable ports on a SAN switch to see how it behaves\n")

    print("Checking to see if the SAN switch is pingable\n")

    test_ping = canPing(deviceIP)

    if test_ping:
        print("The switch is pingable, let's proceed !\n")
    else:
        print("This device is not pingable unfortunately, sorry... : (\n")
        sys.exit(-1)

    sshConnection = connectToSSH(deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword)

    while True:
        optionPrinter()

        user_input = input("Select an option from the menu\n")

        switch_result = mySwitch_function(user_input)

        if switch_result == 'ShowPort':
            portShow(sshConnection)
        elif switch_result == 'SwitchShow':
            switchShow(sshConnection)
        elif switch_result == 'EnablePort':
            enablePort(sshConnection)
        elif switch_result == 'DisablePort':
            disablePort(sshConnection)
        elif switch_result == 'disableEnable':
            disableEnableIteration(sshConnection)
        else:
            print("Program is exiting now, have a great day/night ! \n")
            sys.exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the option names before the parameters.

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'our_Switch.py', '-deviceIP', deviceIP, '-deviceUsername', deviceUsername, '-devicePassword', devicePassword])
```

However, it would probably be cleaner if you changed these other scripts into Python modules that you could simply import and call directly as functions, rather than running them as subprocesses.

Comment: @Bamar I love you, you made my day ! I will checkmark your answer (it says wait 7 minutes). You are a hero !

Comment: @Bamar Can you explain why it would be best to import these scripts as functions ? There are a lot of functions within these files and I didn't make classes for them because it was easier to just write out functions with no classes (I'm fairly new to python to be honest, go easy on me)

Comment: Because you're creating unnecessary processes, and going through extra argument formatting and parsing. Commands are for humans, functions are for programs.

Comment: @Bamar It will slow down my program by using subprocesses ?

Comment: A little, but that's not the point. You're just making things more complex.

Comment: However, if the command is already written, this is the path of least resistance.

Comment: That was just a stylistic suggestion. I've changed "best" to be less emphatic.